# Schedule ECS task in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks, amazon-ecs, aws-ecs

I am trying to write a cron expression to schedule a ECS task which will run as per given time. For example between 13 : 00 to 13 : 15.What will be the cron expression.

Comment: similarity is usually considered to be commutative so either both of those statements are correct or neither is, depending on how you define "similar to". Preorder is one particular style of DFS. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Pre-Order traversal on a binary tree same as Depth First Search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571745/is-pre-order-traversal-on-a-binary-tree-same-as-depth-first-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your graph is a tree then pre-order traversal is a type of DFS.
You have three different tree-traversal styles (pre-order, in-order, post-order). They are all types of DFS.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for more information.